# Return from standby mode opens grub

Tags: linux, windows, grub2, standby

After installing Windows 8 and Arch Linux as dual boot everything worked pretty well. However if I happen to close my laptop lid while in Win8 (the comp goes to standby mode) and then reopen my computer later Grub is opened as if the computer was restarted instead of just stand by.

My problem is that I have an ntfs partition in my fstab and if there is some traces in the partition that Windows still uses it then Arch boot fails and goes to recovery mode.

As such is there a way to make it so that when returning from standby it would start directly to Windows (as normally happens) instead of opening Grub?

Comment: Does it resume ok if you choose win 8 from grub?

Comment: It does.  Usually I just don't eyeball the process so Grub will automatically load the default OS which in my case is Arch.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Recall_previous_entry

You set

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

and

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

in `/etc/default/grub` (and re-create the Grub config). This will make Grub remember your last used OS, and thus if Windows hibernates (or crashes) it will automatically boot back into Windows, same with Linux.